# Why is function executing recursively with using reactive()

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have an annoying bug in my App, which I fully don't understand. In the function checkRule():

If I run only the green code, you see console.log runs exactly enter code here twice, because there are 2 empty values on mandatory columns, so far so correct.

If I run green and red code, both console.log are executing recursively?! which I absolute don't understand. When I remove the reactive() [marked in orange] of the variable errors, everything runs well.

So, I suggest the problem has to do with reactive() - have you any idea, why is that?

```js
<script setup>
import { reactive } from 'vue'

let errors = reactive([]);
  
const product_columns = [
    { name: "name", mandatory: true },
    { name: "brand", mandatory: false }
];
  
const products = [
  { id: 1, name: "Product1", brand: "TestBrand" },
  { id: 2, name: "", brand: "" },
  { id: 3, name: "Product3", brand: "TestBrand" },
  { id: 4, name: "", brand: "TestBrand" },
  { id: 5, name: "Product5", brand: "TestBrand" },
  { id: 6, name: "Product6", brand: "" },
  { id: 7, name: "Product7", brand: "TestBrand" },
];

function checkRule(name, value, index) {
  if (value == "") {
    // If column name is mandatory
    if(product_columns.find(product => product.name === name).mandatory) {
      // Console log on product with index 1 and 3, because "name" is empty there
      console.log("Column " + name + " is mandatory on index: " + (index));
      
      errors.push("Testerror");
      console.log(errors);
      
      // Return error class
      return "bg-red-100"
    }
  }
  
}
</script>

<template>
  <div v-for="(product, index) in products" :key="product.id">
    <div :class="checkRule('name', product.name, index)">
      {{ product.name }}
    </div>
    <div :class="checkRule('brand', product.brand, index)">
      {{ product.brand }}
    </div>
    <br>
  </div>
</template>
```

[image: Results of console.log()]

[VueSFC Playground - Demo](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNqdVFFv2jAQ/isnv0BVSIqqbVIGlbY+7W2q9jZPUwgXcJvYke2kQ4j/vrMdp0AZ28oDju3P3+e7+8479qlpkq5FlrG5KbRoLBi0bXPHpagbpS3sQGNeWNEh7KHUqoYR4UdcclmhBdRaaQML+P7jI5cAXBZKGguNVqu2sD8LVbW19AA6Yncg8xoz4MyNnE2gzuUqt0pvM7C6JZHJMW6pCXACLPPKEJLLs5q9GNDVI8nXsDNzPJ7QLX5DYz8Hdq96eOAIeGa/J7x9G+ElYM/87n8PvP/HK3+4SOwSymXZSqq4klBssHh6aCscO5YJdHnV0iDkCn9dwc4JiBLGfhkWCy/crwOkKXwpIRjA3wKEealiwIhyfOKUpCT2uAiLu1jVxDMsSMR9XCUD0aDnFe/JCapCqNQaKIDI8yzsJlwbZkAn4ZaSgEXeko+iF931sG7sFuwGNUZS5y1iTIhxzNl9CIfQ1yGma/d9GJiT9Uouv7Q9Dtm68lZ1vziG1kma1myI2FXCr1AGB+ihdoC/pqGgH6hltQyEUFS5MXFThx1qo/VU42o6u7mhGvlNap/+j0sa5mnof+p8mlhKRJVbpBnAfCU66Kal0gvOYmkGF4ghy4bizZ5wS6hYNEHG8hw9S+ZvR4AXZ41cGkeTozpH8uEwGXl37IS9vzrRpsT7Nwnv9wMNP78s4iHnVZY6pKVfm6dDttiEhWdzWudN8miUpIfV25P3G5SjLBqWM3pJ3ZyzjbWNydLUlIV7jh9NovQ6pa9Et9KKGhM09XSp1bNBTcTUxAccKS12qKnCFJBGstCfOU+gr3h7V+zZ/jek8gHU)

Comment: You force an update when the template is rendered, this causes another update, this is the recursion. Don't do side effects in things that are used in the template, specifically checkRule

Comment: Thank you a lot! Now I understand the problem.